# Are the the elongation the same when one end of a spring is attached to the wall and

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

Consider there are 2 identical springs.

- One end of the first spring is attached to the wall and the other end is pulled by a force $\vec{F}$. It is depicted as shown in the first figure below.
- Both ends of the second spring is pulled by a force $\vec{F}$. It is depicted as shown in the second figure below.

[image]

Is the elongation for the first case identical to the second case?

Comment: Related by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92799/is-my-free-diagram-of-a-spring-stretched-on-one-end-and-attached-to-the-wall-on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Spring elongation is $\delta= \frac{F}{k}$ regardless of where $F$ comes from.

Comment: Does it imply that it is impossible to use a different force on one end of the spring? For example, in the second case, 2 N on the left end and 3 N on the right end?

Comment: Yes, because it is a massless spring, and hece a force only element. The forces must balance out on both ends. Only if the spring has mass can the ends have different forces.